How to get value of a radio button choice using javascript in LaTex form?
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=sseq]{}{1=132}
\ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=sseq]{}{2=132}

I'm creating this radio field using which I need to redirect the user of the form to a specific page.  To achieve this, I need to get the selected value e.g. 132 if 1 is selected.   I've tried using the following code. But I get no output in the text field.
\TextField[width=1cm, calculate={var sel = this.getField("sseq").value; event.value = sel }]{S2} \\


Welcome to TeX.SE!
